# Elements from xml using php

Tags: php, xml, foreach

so I can access an xml file and all its elements using

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');
```

Inside there are items and some of them have images, some more than others. I, of course, receive this file from another server. These images live inside an element called 'images' and the xml file looks like this:

```
<images>
    <image id="1" time_modif="1490197696"> 
        *** url here   ***
    </image >
    <image id="2" time_modif="1490197699">
        *** url here   ***
    </ image >
    <image id="3" time_modif="1490197702">
        *** url here   ***
    </image >
</images >
```

I am in desperate need to loop through these images and get their Url. For that I've tried:

```
$element = $xml->element;
$i = 0;


foreach ($element->images as $img) 
{
    echo $img->image[$i] . '<br>';
    $i++
}
```

but the 'foreach' loop only returns the first url, and not the others.

Does anyone have any thoughts?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@martin, can you give full structure on one of the image elements within the , as I believe you're trying to load directly from the XML file.

In the meantime, I suggest you read the following for help

- https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_simplexml_load_file.asp
- http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-parse-xml-with-php5

This shows you how to access required item(s) inform of array.

Hope this helps

Comment: this did the trick for me ! Thanks for your help !  `  $xml = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');
    $bien = $xml->bien[0];


    foreach($bien->images->children() as $child)
      {
      echo $child . "<br>";
      }
`

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

[**PHP code demo**](https://eval.in/765904)

```
<?php
$domObject= new DOMDocument();
$domObject->loadXML('<images>
    <image id="1" time_modif="1490197696"> 
        http://example.com/1.jpg
    </image >
    <image id="2" time_modif="1490197699">
        http://example.com/2.jpg
    </image>
    <image id="3" time_modif="1490197702">
        http://example.com/3.jpg
    </image >
</images >');

foreach($domObject->getElementsByTagName("image") as $nodeObj)
{
    $imageLink=trim($nodeObj->nodeValue);
    print_r($imageLink);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK - I've changed it to 'load_string' for my example, but this works fine.  I think that you maybe overcomplicating it?

```
$file = '
<images>
    <image id="1" time_modif="1490197696"> 
       http://www.image123.com
    </image>
    <image id="2" time_modif="1490197699">
        http://www.image234.com
    </image>
    <image id="3" time_modif="1490197702">
        http://www.image456.com
    </image>
</images >';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($file);

foreach ($xml as $img) 
{
    echo $img.'<br>';
}
```

Outputs:

http://www.image123.com

http://www.image234.com

http://www.image456.com

Comment: You're right, this works, but if hard-coded. If I get these elements loaded from the xml file, it does not work

Answer (score 0):

```
 foreach ($element->images as $img) { echo $img->image[$i] . '<br>'; $i++ }
```

There's no image[ ] array declared ,so just try

```
echo $img;
```

And it has to loop through it

Comment: May be but still the array you have tried first is not declared so try another